# stopped unfortunately after adding the statement of notifyDataSetChaged()

Tags: java, android

I got in the data and converted them into what object I want and added them to the ArrayList which is ToDoItems(I've checked what I said above by Toast). Now I notified the adapter to fresh the screen. But error occurs. There's only one adapter and I created this method in the activity where this adapter is.

```
public void getImport(){
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    FileInputStream inStream = null;
    File file = new File(getCacheDir(),"list1.txt");

    try {strong text
        String data = null;
        inStream = new FileInputStream(file);

        byte fileContent[] = new byte[(int)file.length()];

        inStream.read(fileContent);

        data = new String(fileContent);
        if(data == null){
            Toast.makeText(this, "No data to import", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else{
            todoItems.clear();
            String[] token = data.split("$$");
            for(int i = 0;i<token.length;i++){
                todoItems.add(i, gson.fromJson(token[i], ToDoItem.class));
            }
            aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        inStream.close();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Import Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "FileNotFoundException", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "IOEXCEPTION", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: where is aa declared?

Comment: aa is an adapter and can u show where u declared adapter